# How to allocate an array with NULL

Tags: c

Can someone tell me how should I do to allocate every `v[i].word` and next with `NULL`?

```
Struct hash{
Char*word;
Hash*next;
}*v[10];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I recommend you post compilable code.  Note that C is case sensitive, so `Struct hash` is a syntax error under most circumstances — unless one or the other of the words is a macro.  Similarly, `Char` is not a regular type.  The `Hash` referred to in the body of the structure is wholly unrelated to the hypothetical `struct hash` (or `struct Hash`).  It is highly recommended that you post compilable code — see MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and note 'minimal'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `for` loop, let it iterate from `i = 0` to `9`. In each iteration, allocate one `struct hash` and point `v[i]` to it. Afterwards, initialize `*v[i]` as needed. Don't forget to check if `malloc()` failed.